# How to determine Distance between points using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, distance

I am trying to figure out the distance between points based on 1000+ points using ArcMap 10.2.

I have transit stops and am trying to figure out how far from stop 1 to stop 2, stop 2 to stop 3, stop 3 to stop 4, stop 4 to stop 5 etc.

Is there a way to do this in ArcMap through the use of a tool?

I'm not good at programming so writing a script is out. Any ideas?

Comment: So, to clarify, you need the distance between a series of each successive points?  If so I would say use route analysis as mentioned before.  If this is not an option, I believe it would have to be scripted.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have just the standard license so I guess I will try the ettools as I'm not a programmer - I'll let you know if I have any success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is free tool in [ettools](http://www.ian-ko.com).
Geo wizards>free functions>closest feature distance.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have just the standard license so I guess I will try the ettools - I'll let you know if I have any success!

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! Very cool! Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to Network Analysis - and your bus routes are connected and directionally accurate - you can use this to determine distances.  This would give you the distance along the route as opposed to as the crow flys.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004700000001000000

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I have just the standard license so I guess I will try the ettools - I'll let you know if I have any success!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have an **Advanced** level license (you do not specify otherwise), then I think the tool to try is **[Point Distance (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001r000000)**:

> Determines the distances from input point features to all points in
>   the near features within a specified search radius.

Note that this will give you "as the crow flies" distances rather than distances along roads (you do not specify which you may be after).

Comment: If you supply the input and near as the same feature class it will return the distance between every point and every other point (within a search radius) this will return potentially a square of the count of input features. You can safely remove the distance = 0 records as they are the same but you will definitely have a lot of choices in the output table to sort through.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I have just the standard license so I guess I will try the ettools - I'll let you know if I have any success!